# How can I create and update a subcollection using Angular Firestore?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have created a Collection "Person" in Firestore. I am able to create a document and fields from code.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.personCol = this.afs.collection('person');
//snapshotChanges is used to retreive the document data and other metadata, which includes the ID
//we need ID to edit or delete a record
this.person = this.personCol.snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
   return actions.map(a => {
     const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Person;
     const id = a.payload.doc.id;
     return { id, data };
   });
  });}
addPerson() {
this.afs.collection('person').add({
  'name': this.name,
  'age': this.age,
});}
getPerson(PersonId) {
this.personDoc = this.afs.doc('person/'+personId);
this.singlePerson = this.personDoc.valueChanges();
```

}

Now I want to add a list of books that the person borrows:

```
Person: 
{Name: "John"
 Age: 32 
 Books: {Title: "First book", Author: "Some author"
         Title: "Second book" Author: "Another author"},
{Name: "Anne"
 Age: 21
 Books: {Title: "How to... book", Author: "Author Name"
         Title: "Flowers book" Author: "Another author"}
```

How can I create the `Books` subcollection using Angular? 
How can I access `Books` subcollection to update the `title` and `author` from code?

Comment: Even though **[firebase recommends flattening your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure)**, you will find your answer **[in the documentation, under the data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)**. You need to create a reference and append it to your document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the subcollection of books for a specific person:

```
this.personBooks = this.afs.collection('person/'+personId+'/Books');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to Frank van Puffelen I found a solution for adding a sub-collection. First I'm creating a person and display a list of all persons.

```
addPerson() {
 this.afs.collection('person').add({
  'name': this.name,
  'age': this.age
  });
}
```

When I click one person in the list I get personId and then I'm adding books in `books` sub-collection:

```
addBook(personId) {
 this.afs.collection('person/' + personId + '/books').add({
  'book': this.book
 });
}
```

If `books` was created before then the book is added to that collection, if not first it creates the `books` sub-collection and add the first book.